# How to access data from firestore in .ts file

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I don't know how to access the data in my .ts file in angular that I pulling from my firestore database.  The problem I am having is I can't figure out how to access the json data inside the .ts file.  I found one question

[Not able to access JSON data into angular(.ts) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125298/not-able-to-access-json-data-into-angular-ts-file)

But the answer didn't quite make sense and it didn't work for me when I attempted to implement it.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { moveIn, fallIn, moveInLeft } from '../router.animations';



interface User {
  email: string;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  uid: string;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-members',
  templateUrl: './members.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./members.component.css'],
  animations: [moveIn(), fallIn(), moveInLeft()],
  host: {'[@moveIn]': ''}

})



export class MembersComponent implements OnInit {


  state: string = '';
  name: any;
  user_data: any;


  userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;
  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth,private router: Router, private afs: AngularFirestore) {

      this.af.authState.subscribe(auth => { 
      if(auth) {
          getAccountName();

          this.userDoc = this.afs.doc("users_real/" + auth.uid);
          this.user = this.userDoc.valueChanges();
          console.log(this.user);

          this.name = auth;


        }
      });


  }

  logout() {
     this.af.auth.signOut();
     console.log('logged out');
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }


  ngOnInit() {

  }



}
```

html below

```
<div class="form-container" id="toolbar">
    <header [@fallIn]="state">
      <button (click)="logout()" class="basic-btn">Logout</button>
    </header>
    <div id="page" [@moveInLeft]="state">
      <h2>Hey {{ user | async | json }}!</h2>

      <img src="assets/images/filler.png" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is an Observable. To correctly create the `user` and `userDoc` attributes you have to transform the `authState` Observable using RxJS operators.

```
this.userDoc = this.af.authState.map(auth => auth ?  this.afs.doc(`users_real/${auth.uid}`) : null);
```

So now you have a userDoc Observable, if the user is logged in it will point to a location in Firestore; else null.

```
this.user = this.userDoc.switchMap(doc => doc ? doc.valueChanges() : of(null))
```

Now we `switchMap` which replaces the Observable with a new Observable, aborting prior Firestore listeners; or returning an Observable of null.

Your view will now work as expected.